# Loop to update column is not working correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with data in `Column A` and `Column B`, I want to update `Column C` based on a condition that If
`cellB` is found in `cellA`, then `cellB` is written in `Column C` on the row of the match from `column A`.
With the help of the community, I have managed to come up with something but
can someone please tell me why the below `loop` only works for a few number of rows?
Also, sometimes `Column B` can be blank, is this a problem? If so, can i skip it if blank?

This works (perhaps its because all the cells have data in them):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim cellB As Range
Dim cellA As Range

For Each cellB In Range("b2:b5")
For Each cellA In Range("a2:a5")
If InStr(cellA, cellB) > 0 Then
Range("c" & cellA.Row) = cellB
End If
Next cellA
Next cellB

End Sub
```

This attempts to update `Column C` but the `cellB` values are never updated in the `Column C` (perhaps its because `Column B` contain nulls?):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim cellB As Range
Dim cellA As Range

For Each cellB In Range("b2:b500")
For Each cellA In Range("a2:a500")
If InStr(cellA, cellB) > 0 Then
Range("c" & cellA.Row) = cellB
End If
Next cellA
Next cellB
End Sub
```

Snapshot of the worksheet:

[image]

Comment: Does the complete value in column `A` have to be equal to the value in column `B`, or just a part? Is this search to be case-sensitive (`A<>a`) or not(`A=a`)?

Comment: @VBasic2008 a complete value of column `B` needs to exits in `A` this is because `A` can be `Z251297` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, plase. It will process all existing range, based on the A:A column filled range. It uses an array to collect the processing result and it should be fast enough:

```
Dim cellB As Range, cellA As Range, sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
Dim arrfin As Variant

 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet
 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 ReDim arrfin(1 To lastRow, 1 To 1)

 sh.Range("C:C").Clear
 For Each cellA In Range("a2:a" & lastRow)
    For Each cellB In Range("b2:b" & lastRow)
        If cellA.value <> "" And cellB.value <> "" Then
            If InStr(cellA.value, cellB.value) > 0 Then
                arrfin(cellA.row, 1) = cellB.value
            End If
        End If
    Next cellB
 Next cellA
 sh.Range("C1").Resize(UBound(arrfin, 1), UBound(arrfin, 2)).value = arrfin
```

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately the same problem occur. I have uploaded a snapshot of the worksheet if it helps. Thanks

Comment: @Fil: Are you sure that there are occurrences of cellB in cellA?

Comment: yes, using your code, even if I try to manually create value in cellB to match a value in cellA, the code finds it and attempts to update `column C` but the value soon disappears from the column.

Comment: @Fil:  I tested the code in a test sheet, and it works as expected. Please try putting in A:A: aaa, bb, cc, dd, aa, vv, bb and in B:B: aa, r, c, gg, aa, v, fg. Running the above code, the C:C column will contain: aa, ,c,  , aa, v, ,. Try please such a test worksheet and then see what is wrong with your data in the processed sheet.

Comment: as I mention in the OP this works fine with a fairly small number of rows of data, my issue is that it doesn't work with a much greater number of rows. My worksheet contains more than 500 rows and that is my main problem.

Comment: @Fil: If the big number of iterations is the code problem, I will post a variant using arrays...

Comment: @Fil: Try the updated code, please. Is should be very fast...

Comment: @FaneDuran Just tried your latest code and it is not doing anything at all.

Comment: @Fil: Did you check the code **as it is**? Trying to process the active sheet? If yes, can you share your workbook? [Here](https://easyupload.io/) you can find a transfer site easy to use. Only upload your workbook and copy here the produced link. In a couple of minutes  I will tell you where is the problem.

Comment: @FaneDuran I have also figured out that the previous code you posted only stops working is `cellB` is detected empty

Comment: @Fil: Try the updated code, please. It is a mixture between the two variants. It uses an array to drop the processing result at once. This is the part which consumes most of Excel resources... It takes about 4 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: This is much shift and seems to doing something now. Only problem is the values in column C is placed in the row corresponding to cell B but i intend to placed it the row that matches Cell A. Any possibility to please edit so I can mark this as complete?

Comment: @Fil: Updated. Please test the last version and send some feedback.

Comment: @Fil: Glad I (finally) could help! It was difficult to understand where is the problem only trying to deduce what your code should do, without seeing the ranges to be processed...

Answer (score 0):

### 'For Next' vs 'For Each Next' feat. 'Range' vs 'Cells'

- All five examples do the same thing.
- They are best copied into a standard module (e.g. `Module1`) and are then easily run from **VBE** or called via a Button click event e.g.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub Button2_Click()
    updateForEachNextCellsVersion 
End Sub
```

---

- There are two **For** loops: the `For Next` loop and the `For Each Next` loop.
- The first two examples use the `For Each Next` loop, while the remaining two use the `For Next` loop.
- The 1st and 3rd example use `Cells`, while the 2nd and 4th use `Range`.
- Why would you use `Cells` when `Range` is so much easier? You should know both. The biggest downside of `Range` is that you cannot loop through a row incrementing the columns. For this task only `Cells` can be used.
- The usage of `Cells` with column numbers is shown in the 5th example.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub updateForEachNextCellsVersion()
    
    ' Calculate the row of the last non-blank cell in column A.
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Declare the cell ranges for column A and B.
    Dim celA As Range, celB As Range
    ' Loop through rows of column A.
    For Each celA In Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(LastRow, "A")).Cells
        ' Loop through rows of column B.
        For Each celB In Range(Cells(2, "B"), Cells(LastRow, "B")).Cells
            ' Check if the current cell in column B is not blank.
            If Not IsEmpty(celB) Then
                ' Check if the values of the current cells in columns A and B
                ' are equal.
                If celA.Value = celB.Value Then
                    ' Write value of current cell in column B to
                    ' column C, to the row of current cell in column A.
                    Cells(celA.Row, "C").Value = celB.Value
                End If
            End If
        Next celB
    Next celA
    
End Sub

Sub updateForEachNextRangeVersion()
    
    ' Calculate the row of the last non-blank cell in column A.
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Declare the cell ranges for column A and B.
    Dim celA As Range, celB As Range
    ' Loop through rows of column A.
    For Each celA In Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Cells
    ' or: For Each celA In Range("A2", "A" & LastRow).Cells
        ' Loop through rows of column B.
        For Each celB In Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Cells
        ' or: For Each celB In Range("B2", "B" & LastRow).Cells
            ' Check if the current cell in column B is not blank.
            If Not IsEmpty(celB) Then
                ' Check if the values of the current cells in columns A and B
                ' are equal.
                If celA.Value = celB.Value Then
                    ' Write value of current cell in column B to
                    ' column C, to the row of current cell in column A.
                    Range("C" & celA.Row).Value = celB.Value
                End If
            End If
        Next celB
    Next celA
    
End Sub

Sub updateForNextCellsVersion()
    
    ' Calculate the row of the last non-blank cell in column A.
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Declare the counters for the loops (i for column A, j for column B).
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    ' Loop through rows of column A.
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        ' Loop through rows of column B.
        For j = 2 To LastRow
            ' Check if the current cell in column B is not blank.
            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(j, "B")) Then
                ' Check if the values of the current cells in columns A and B
                ' are equal.
                If Cells(i, "A").Value = Cells(j, "B").Value Then
                    ' Write value of current cell in column B to
                    ' column C, to the row of current cell in column A.
                    Cells(i, "C").Value = Cells(j, "B").Value
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub

Sub updateForNextRangeVersion()
    
    ' Calculate the row of the last non-blank cell in column A.
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Declare the counters for the loops (i for column A, j for column B).
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    ' Loop through rows of column A.
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        ' Loop through rows of column B.
        For j = 2 To LastRow
            ' Check if the current cell in column B is not blank.
            If Not IsEmpty(Range("B" & j)) Then
                ' Check if the values of the current cells in columns A and B
                ' are equal.
                If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("B" & j).Value Then
                    ' Write value of current cell in column B to
                    ' column C, to the row of current cell in column A.
                    Range("C" & i).Value = Range("B" & j).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub

Sub updateForNextCellsColumnNumbersVersion()
    
    ' Calculate the row of the last non-blank cell in column A.
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Declare the counters for the loops (i for column A, j for column B).
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    ' Loop through rows of column A.
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        ' Loop through rows of column B.
        For j = 2 To LastRow
            ' Check if the current cell in column B is not blank.
            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(j, 2)) Then
                ' Check if the values of the current cells in columns A and B
                ' are equal.
                If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(j, 2).Value Then
                    ' Write value of current cell in column B to
                    ' column C, to the row of current cell in column A.
                    Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(j, 2).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: First of all you rock, I have used example 5 but the loop stops soon as `CellB` is detected as empty and does not proceed with the check. Anything i am doing wrong?